# Swapping function implementation does not work

Tags: python

Suppose, I have a 3rd party library that I am not allowed to modify. Suppose, it is called Fabric, but that is important only to explain the symptoms.

The script processes a list of existing files to get them using `fabric.operations.get`, which in its turn calls `fabric.sftp.SFTP.get`. Using `fabric.sftp.SFTP.get` produced some `Warning: get() encountered an exception while downloading ... Underlying exception: Permission denied`. I noticed the implementation was too old, and swapped the implementation of that function for one that uses sudo to work around the `Permission denied`:

```
import fabric.sftp
def sftpget(....same args as in current implementation....):
  ...here I pasted fabric.sftp.SFTP.get from the Internet
# swapping the implementation
fabric.sftp.SFTP.get=sftpget
```

This worked in 99.999% of cases. But getting three files still results in the same error. I tried to see if that is caused by some other codepath, but the only place where that string is printed is in `fabric.operations.get` in `except:` clause (grepped `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/` for `get() encountered an exception while downloading`). I tried to swap that function for a implementation that will print the stack trace of the exception, but I still only get the `Permission denied` message, and *no stack trace*.

It looks like the function does not get swapped in this case.

What could be the reasons for some invocations to use the original `fabric.operations.get` (since I don't see the stack traces printed) (and possibly the unpatched `fabric.sftp.SFTP.get`, since it seems sudo fix is not being used - I did check manually that those operations can be done on those files)?

Answer (score 0):

during import, before you replace the get function some other piece of code might save a reference to the get function, for example:

```
class a():
    def __init__(self,getter):
        self.getter=getter

b=a(sftp.SFTP.get)
```

class a would then still hold a reference to the old piece of code despite it being replaced by you in the namespace.

Comment: how to find the culprit?

Comment: might be hidden pretty good, might be easy to find by grepping through the code for "SFTP.get"